# How to deserialize json string to list of objects which type I get at runtime?

Tags: c#, serialization, c#-4.0, deserialization

I want to deserialize json string to list of objects which type I get at runtime.

For example:

my json string is `[{"id":"1", "name":"test"},{"id":"2", "name":"test2"}]` and the type I get is `"Types.type1, types.dll"`, so I need to deserialize it to `List<type1>`. If I will get the type `"Types.type2, types.dll"` so I need to deserialize it to `List<type2>`

How I can do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `DataContractJsonSerializer` in `System.Runtime.Serialization`

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Bar { get; set; }
    public int Baaz { get; set; }
}


class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DataContractJsonSerializer serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<Foo>));
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(
            Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("[{\"Bar\":\"Bar\",\"Baaz\":2}]"));

        var list = (List<Foo>)serializer.ReadObject(ms);

        Console.WriteLine(list.Count);
    }
}
```

To solve the problem of having it in runtime, use below:

```
Type.GetType("System.Collections.Generic.List`1[[TestDll.TestType, TestDll]]")
```

Comment: This is how .NET framework names generic types. It means this generic type has 1 generic parameter. For example for dictionary, it is `2.