# How to cast List<ClassB> to List<ClassA> when ClassB inherits from ClassA?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, casting

I deserialized json string to `List<ClassB>` and now I want to cast it to `List<ClassA>` before I return it from 
 `BindModel` method. I need casting because the methods expects to get `List<ClassA>`.

Why I get error while casting? After all, `ClassB` inherits from `ClassA`. What should I do?

P.S. this question is extended from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7953214/how-to-deserialize-json-string-to-list-of-objects-which-type-i-get-at-runtime). In line `new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<ClassB>));` instead of `List<ClassB>` the type will be constructed at runtime.

```
    public override object BindModel(...)
    {
          var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<ClassB>));
          MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("[{\"id\":\"1\",\"name\":\"name\"}]"));
          var list = serializer.ReadObject(ms);

          return (List<ClassA>)list;
    }

    [KnownType(typeof(ClassA))]
    [DataContract]
    public class ClassA
    {
        public ClassA();
    }

    [KnownType(typeof(ClassB))]       
    [DataContract]
    public class ClassB : ClassA
    {
        [DataMember(Name = "id")]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        [DataMember(Name = "name")]
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }
    }
```

Comment: Are you sure you're using .NET 4.0? What you want is called `covariance` and should be already supported.

Comment: List<T> does not support covariance.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use

```
 Cast<T>()
```

For example:

```
 List<A> listOfA = new List<B>().Cast<A>();
```

This in fact is **inferior to Linq** and is implemented on `IEnumerable` rather than `IEnumerable<T>` but still is useful. It is **not efficient** since as I said, it tries to cast it.

Remember List does not allow for **covariance** which is a nuisance. It is preferable to use `IEnumerable<T>` as interface rather than List.

You can say:

```
 IEnumerable<B> listOfB = new List<B>();
 IEnumerable<A> listOfA = listOfB; // no casting required
```

Comment: It worked, I changed `List` to `IEnumerable`, since I don't need to add elements later:)

Comment: How is this "inferior to Linq"?  It *is* Linq!

Comment: It is not! As I said it is implemented by `IEnumerable` which is not Linq. But `Cast<T>` turns it to Linq.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [Cast Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb341406.aspx).

`return list.Cast<ClassB>();`

Have a look at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/245607/how-is-generic-covariance-contra-variance-implemented-in-c-sharp-4-0) about Co and Contra Variance

Comment: I'll read the post, but `serializer.ReadObject` return `object` so I cannot use `Cast<T>` and `ClassB` was just example as I said in Postscript(P.S.), any suggastions?

Comment: Cast returns IEnumerable<T>, but the OP needs a List<T>.

Comment: @theateist if serializer.ReadObject retuns an object whose runtime type is List<ClassA> then you can do this (but it returns an enumerable, not a list): `((List<ClassA>)obj).Cast<ClassB>()`.  Even though you can't cast a `List<ClassA>` to `List<ClassB>`, you *can* cast a reference to `List<ClassA>` from `object` to `List<ClassA>`

Answer (score 2):

I would cast the lists like this:

```
var listB = GetListOfB();  // returns List<B>
var listA = listB.Select(q => (A)q).ToList();
```

Will that work for you?

Comment: +1, but why use `.Select(q => (A)q)` rather than `.Cast<A>()`?

Answer (score 1):

You can't cast a List of *SubType* to a List of *SuperType*. Suppose I have a list of Tortoises, and I was able to cast it to a list of Animals. Then I could add a lion, to a list of Tortoises, but a Lion isn't of the correct type.

With enumerables, you can do this, however. The previous posters are quite correct in saying that you can cast a List of *SubType* to an IEnumerable of *SuperType*. In fact, in C# 4, and IEnumerable *SubType* is an IEnumerable of *SuperType*. This is because the generic parameter is specified as an out parameter.

Answer (score 1):

To create a `List<BaseClass>` from a `List<DerivedClass>`, a cast will not suffice, as other answers have noted.  You need to construct a new list.

I'm not particularly happy with the code that other answers have suggested, though, so I'm offering my own solution.  I would do it this way:

```
var baseClassList = new List<BaseClass>(derivedClassList.Cast<BaseClass>());
```

Some might prefer this:

```
var baseClassList = derivedClassList.Cast<BaseClass>().ToList();
```

I prefer the first one because it makes it easy to change the type from `List<T>` to any other collection with a constructor that takes an `IEnumerable<T>`.