# How to cast List<object> to List<SomethingElse>

Tags: c#, generics

How can i cast a `List<object>` to `List<SomethingElse>`?

(*where `SomethingElse` is known to descend from `object`*)

---

**Bonus Chatter**

Casting the list:

```
List<Object> first = ...;

List<SomethingElse> second = (List<SomethingElse>)first;
```

doesn't work:

> Cannot convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'

Casting the list:

```
List<SomethingElse> second = first.Cast<SomethingElse>();
```

doesn't work:

> Cannot implicitely convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'

i don't actually need the full `List<T>` object, just an `ICollection<T>` will do:

```
ICollection<SomethingElse> second = first;
ICollection<SomethingElse> second = (ICollection<SomethingElse>)first;
ICollection<SomethingElse> second = first.Cast<SomethingElse>();
```

don't work.

Comment: Related? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1266014/c-sharp-casting-a-listobjbase-as-listobj

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7955890/how-to-cast-listclassb-to-listclassa-when-classb-inherits-from-classa

Comment: Would this work? List<SomethingElse> second = first.Select(o => (SomethingElse)o).ToList();

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Shorter syntax for casting from a List<X> to a List<Y>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5115275/shorter-syntax-for-casting-from-a-listx-to-a-listy)

Answer (score 54, accepted):

LINQ, as implemented through the extension methods within the [`Enumerable`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.aspx) class, relies on deferred execution:

> Methods that are used in a query that returns a sequence of values do not consume the target data until the query object is enumerated. This is known as deferred execution.

`Cast<T>` does not create a new list immediately, but rather stores all the information that is required to perform the action. The list would only get enumerated when required (for example, through a `foreach` statement).

In your case, if you simply intend to iterate over the sequence, you should consider sticking to the `IEnumerable<T>` interface, which is the declared return type of `Cast<T>`:

```
IEnumerable<SomethingElse> second = first.Cast<SomethingElse>();
foreach (SomethingElse se in second)
{
    // ...
}
```

This is efficient, since it only performs the cast as each item is iterated.

If you’re convinced you want a new list to be created immediately, use `ToList`:

```
List<SomethingElse> second = first.Cast<SomethingElse>().ToList();
```

**Edit**: Replying to point posted in comment:

It depends on what you mean by “a list that can be modified”. There are several LINQ query operators that will allow you to alter the definition of your query further. For example, if you want to remove all `SomethingElse` elements whose `IsDeleted` property is `true`, you can use the `Where` operator:

```
IEnumerable<SomethingElse> second = first.Cast<SomethingElse>();
second = second.Where(element => !element.IsDeleted);
```

If you want to add a sequence of new elements, you can use the `Concat` operator:

```
second = second.Concat(anotherCollectionOfSomethingElse);
```

If you want to sort your sequence in ascending order of `ID`, use the `OrderBy` operator:

```
second = second.OrderBy(element => element.ID);
```

Each time, we’re applying a query operator over the former definition of our query, and assigning the new (composite) query to our `second` variable. LINQ would store all your operators in the query definition. Then, when the sequence is actually enumerated (for example, through a `foreach` or `ToList`), it would give you the composite result of your sequence, with all the query operators applied in order.

As with all cases of deferred execution / lazy evaluation, be careful not to go overboard with this. If, for example, you’re going to apply a `Where` operator which will reduce the size of your sequence drastically, it might make sense to execute the query eagerly and store the enumerated list instead.

Comment: i don't need a new list to be created immediately; but i do need a list that that can be modified, and isn't limited by the covariance problem. If `ToList` is what i need in order to get what i need, the i need to use it. i would, of course, prefer that the returned `List` was a wrapper around the `first`, allowing deferred execution as well.

Answer (score 29):

You have the option of using either `Cast` or `OfType`. `Cast` will throw an exception if you cannot cast to the type specified. `OfType` on the other hand will return only those items in the list that can be cast to the specified type. I would recommend using `OfType` in your situation.

```
List<Foo> fooList = myList.OfType<Foo>().ToList();
```

Answer (score 23):

I think you're close with the `Cast<T>` expression.  The difference is that `Cast<T>` returns an `IEnumerable<T>`, not a `List<T>`.

Try this:

```
IEnumerable<SomethingElse> second = first.Cast<SomethingElse>();
```

You can get a list by doing something similar:

```
List<SomethingElse> second = first.Cast<SomethingElse>().ToList();
```