# Select a Collection with same interface

Tags: c#, collections

If have following classen

```
public interface ISomething { int Id { get; set; } }
public class SomethingA : ISomething {...}
public class SomethingB : ISomething {...}
```

In another class I have following two lists:

```
List<SomethingA> aValues;
List<SomethingB> bValues;
```

My question is if there is a possibility to do something like this:

```
public List<ISomething> GetList(bool select) {
    return select ? aValues : bValues;
}
```

My goal is to use this as this:

```
GetList(true).Single(x => x.Id) // or
foreach (var value in GetList(false))
{
    value.Id = 18;
}
// anything else
```

UPDATE: 
I see, there are good possibilities. But is there also a way to also achieve the following?

```
GetList(true).Remove(myValue);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't return `List<ISomething>` because `List<T>` is not covariant and classes can't be. `IEnumerable<T>` is covariant, you may use it as readonly sequence.

Change the method to return `IEnumerable<ISomething>`

```
public static IEnumerable<ISomething> GetList(bool select)
{
    return select ? (IEnumerable<ISomething>)aValues :bValues;
}
```

Then do

```
var result = GetList(true).Single(x => x.Id == 0);
foreach (var value in GetList(false))
{
    value.Id = 18;
}
```

As for your update: If you like to remove the item you need to lose some flexibility. I.e Use non generic `IList` as the return type.

```
public static IList GetList(bool select)
{
    return select ? (IList)aValues : bValues;
}
```

Then do

```
IList list = GetList(true);
foreach (var value in list.OfType<ISomething>())//OfType or Cast can be used
{
    if (value.Id == 6)//Whatever condition
    {
        list.Remove(value);
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Some explanation for downvote please? I tested and that works.

Comment: Thank you, +1 by me. This seems the easiest solution so far for most of my cases.

Comment: Why you cannot return a List<ISomething> ? (and I'm not the downvoter :) )

Comment: @DaniCE Because `List<T>` is not covariant but `IEnumerable<T>` is. And that's why you can't return `List<ISomething>`

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution may be using Linq Cast() like this:

```
    public List<ISomething> GetList(bool select)
    {
        return (List<ISomething>)(@select ? aValues.Cast<ISomething>() : bValues.Cast<ISomething>());
    }
```

> I see, there are good possibilities. But is there also a way to also achieve the following?
>   GetList(true).Remove(myValue);

To remove from the original lists, you are likely best of with a specialized Remove method on the class in question as others have suggested, as most solutions here return a copy of the original list. 
You may remove the element from a copy of the list quite easily like so, but I understand that's not what you are asking.

```
    var result = GetList(true);
    result.Remove(myValue);
```

Comment: @Adriano Updated my response according to your clarification, as the question was somewhat unclear.

Answer (score 0):

I like the `OfType` extension because it returns the typed list you need

```
var listA = initialList.OfType<TypeA>(); //return List<TypeA>
var listB = initialList.OfType<TypeB>(); //return List<TypeB>
```

So in your case you start with

```
var aValues = List<ISomething>.OfType<SomethingA>()
```

and then you can iterate on whichever subcollection you need. Of course you are then working with a IEnumerable, but that can be converted implicitly back to a `IEnumerable<ITest>`.

If you want to filter out values, I would create explicit methods to remove them but it depends on what you need to achieve in the end (for example comparing on a Id instead of the whole object):

```
public IEnumerable<T> Remove<T>(this List<IDisposable> values, T valueToRemove) where T: IComparable
{
    return values.OfType<T>().Where(t => valueToRemove.CompareTo(t) != 0);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can either use the `.Cast<T>` method like this:

```
if (select)
{
    return aValues.Cast<ISomething>().ToList();
}
else
{
    return bValues.Cast<ISomething>().ToList();
}
```

or add all items to a commong Lis() like this:

```
var ret = new List<ISomething>();
if (select)
{
    ret.AddRange(aValues);
}
else
{
    ret.AddRange(bValues);
}
return ret;
```

Since you only want to iterate it, I would write the method like this:

```
public IEnumerable<ISomething> GetList(bool select) {
    return select ? aValues.Cast<ISomething>() : bValues.Cast<ISomething>();
}
```

You can also look at this [StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7955890/how-to-cast-listclassb-to-listclassa-when-classb-inherits-from-classa).